# programmatically killing Subscriber in another thread (ROSJAVA)

Tags: ros, threads, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The title says it all. I have a subscriber in a separate runnable thread from my main program. When I close my main program, I want to kill the subscriber thread, but calling the stop() method below doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
        public void stop() {
        node.shutdown();
        node = null;
    }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11760/programmatically-killing-subscriber-in-another-thread-(rosjava)/) by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2011-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All subscribers run in separate threads. Shutting down the node used to create the subscriber will also shutdown the subscriber. Are you shutting down the correct node? If so, why do you believe the subscriber is still running? Are there any interesting log messages?

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-01-27**:
This question is a bit outdated, but currently the correct way to have an arbitrary thread shutdown with the Node is to use Node.executeCancellableLoop()

**Comment by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on 2011-11-22**:
After further testing, the node itself does seem to shutdown (no longer listed in rostopic list -v. The runnable thread containting that node should then die, but doesn't. so I guess my question is not ROSJAVA specific, but do you have any tips on how to kill that Runnable?